# How can I tell if I'm infected with zombie-virus?

Tags: no-more-room-in-hell

In NMRiH, it is possible to become infected with zombie, but because there is no/little HUD (can't see health, can't see ammo remaining without ammo checking, no minimap), I have been infected in the past without realizing it, which is really a shame because even on full health, after a while you will simply drop dead (without phalanx pills). Is the slight "cracking" shader around the edges the way to tell, or is a certain attack the only way that zombies infect you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that cracking effect crawling in from the edges of the screen is the infection indicator. The more it covers, the closer you are to turning - it may start slight, but by the time you turn, it obscures your vision almost completely.

Zombies seem to only be able to infect you through biting, which is usually preceded by grabbing.

Comment: Ok, I had noticed them grabbing you before but was unable to detach them before they could bite. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, hit V to shove them away.